# MySQL user full permission to own databases

Tags: mysql

Is there a way of giving a user full permissions to create new databases etc, but cannot access or see databases created by other users? 
I need multiple users to be able to create their own databases as if super user, but not be able to effect other user databases.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this may help.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `new_user\_%` .  * TO 'new_user'@'%';

this will grant new_user only access to database created by himself. You can do the same with others.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the DB doesn't exist and user want to create a new one?

Comment: database does not have to exist yet. new_user can login and create the database.

Comment: Does this require all the databases to have the corresponding username as prefix? I need to do this for each database the user will create?

Comment: I guess what I need to a MySQL installation for each user.